# Reading two data sets in for one matplotlib plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I try to plot two data sets in one plot, including errorbars. It worked perfectly fine for one data set. But in this "solution" :

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f2 = open('data1.txt', 'r')
lines = f2.readlines()
f2.close()

f3 = open('data2.txt', 'r')
lines2 = f3.readlines()
f3.close()

x1 = []
y1 = []
xerr1 = []
yerr1 = []

x2 = []
y2 = []
xerr2 = []
yerr2 = []


for line in lines:
    p = line.split()
    x1.append(float(p[0]))
    y1.append(float(p[1]))
    xerr1.append(float(p[2]))
    yerr1.append(float(p[3]))

for line2 in lines2:
    k = line2.split()
    x2.append(float(k[0]))
    y2.append(float(k[1]))
    xerr2.append(float(k[2]))
    yerr2.append(float(k[3]))


xv = np.array(x1)
yv = np.array(y1)
xerror = np.array(xerr1)
yerror = np.array(yerr1)

xv2 = np.array(x2)
yv2 = np.array(y2)
xerror2 = np.array(xerr2)
yerror2 = np.array(yerr2)

fig = plt.figure()


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("test", fontweight='bold')    
ax1.set_xlabel('test', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax1.set_ylabel('test', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
ax1.grid(True)
plt.ylim(67.2, 70.75) 
plt.xlim(-45, 30) 


plt.errorbar(xv, yv, xerr=xerror, yerr=yerror, fmt='-o', linestyle='None', color='k', marker='.')
plt.errorbar(xv2, yv2, xerr=xerror2, yerr=yerror2, fmt='-o', linestyle='None', color='k', marker='.')

plt.plot(xv, yv, marker='o', markersize='6', markeredgewidth='0', linestyle='None', linewidth=0, color='b')
plt.plot(xv2, yv2, marker='o', markersize='6', markeredgewidth='0', linestyle='None', linewidth=0, color='r')

plt.show()
```

I only get the error

```
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
File "E:/script.py", line 39, in <module>
        x2.append(float(k[0]))
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not see the error and need some help. Does anybody have an idea what is wrong in this way? I hope it is not too easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an empty line in `for line2 in lines2:`, because it gives a `IndexError: list index out of range` for `k[0]`, meaning that the index `0` does not exist for k in that case.
Be sure that you check that the split result is not empty.

For example:

```
for line2 in lines2:
    k = line2.split()
    if len(k)==0:
       #do something
    else:
       x2.append(float(k[0]))
       y2.append(float(k[1]))
       xerr2.append(float(k[2]))
       yerr2.append(float(k[3]))
```

The same should be done for the first for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that at some point `k=line2.split()` does not have any elements. For example, if the second file has an empty line (as it might have at the end), then the `split` function will give you an empty list